# accumulating values to corresponding key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to locate the positions of bases (A,C,G,T) and put them into a dictionary corresponding to their positions.

I am working from a text file that has lines of bases like below

```
----T
C
-C
-----G
C
-----C
---T
----A
----C
-----G
```

From the information above, I know that

- C is at the 1st position
- C is at the 2nd position
- 3rd position base is unknown
- T is at the 4th position
- C, A, T are at the 5th position
- C, G are are at the 6th position

So far, I have written the code below

```
def chunks(chunks_file):
    set_bases = {}
    with open(chunks_file) as file:
        for line in file:
            for character in line:
                if character.isalpha():
                    letter = character
                    position = line.find(letter) + 1
                    set_bases[position] = {letter}

    return set_bases
```

my current output is:

```
{5: {'C'}, 1: {'C'}, 2: {'C'}, 6: {'G'}, 4: {'T'}}
```

where as the desired output would be :

```
{1: {'C'}, 2: {'C'}, 4: {'T'}, 5: {'C', 'A', 'T'}, 6: {'C', 'G'}}
```

It seems to me that values are not being added to already existing keys, but the new values are replacing the old values.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try `set_bases[position].add(letter)`. Right now you're replacing the dict key with a new set every time.

Comment: Does every line of the file really just contain 0 or more dashes, followed by exactly one instance of A,C,G or T, and then end-of-line? If yes, every line can be reduced to an integer index, and a letter. And you wouldn't even need a regex to do that either, you could use string methods directly. You could declare a list-of-set or list-of-dict of maximum possible line length, then insert each letter directly into the dict/set at the corresponding index. That would allow you to iterate once over the input file, and no need to store its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the following way, taking into consideration that you have a `txt` file:

```
outDict = {}

with open('data.txt', 'r') as inFile:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in inFile if not line == '\n']
    outDict = dict((str(line.count('-')+1),set()) for line in lines)
    for line in lines:
        outDict[str(line.count('-')+1)].update(line[-1])
    print(outDict)
```

Result:

```
{'5': {'C', 'A', 'T'}, '1': {'C'}, '2': {'C'}, '6': {'C', 'G'}, '4': {'T'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the following improvements:

```
import collections

def chunks(filename):
    bases = collections.defaultdict(set)

    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if len(line) > 0:
                for i, char in enumerate(line):
                    if char.isalpha():
                        position = i + 1
                        bases[position].add(char)

    return bases
```

- This code uses `collections.defaultdict` so you don't have to check if the position is present in the dict or not.
- I also use `enumerate()` when iterating over the lines, so you already have the position and don't need to call `line.find()`.

This code can be used as follows:

```
>>> d = chunks('your-file-name.txt')
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {5: {'T', 'C', 'A'}, 1: {'C'}, 2: {'C'}, 6: {'G', 'C'}, 4: {'T'}})

>>> dict(d)
{5: {'C', 'A', 'T'}, 1: {'C'}, 2: {'C'}, 6: {'G', 'C'}, 4: {'T'}}

>>> for k, v in sorted(d.items()):
...     print(k, v)
1 {'C'}
2 {'C'}
4 {'T'}
5 {'C', 'A', 'T'}
6 {'G', 'C'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
def chunks(chunks_file):
    set_bases = {}
    with open(chunks_file) as file:
        for line in file:
            for character in line:
                if character.isalpha():
                    letter = character
                    position = line.find(letter) + 1
                    if position in set_bases:
                        set_bases[position].append(letter)
                    else:
                        set_bases[position] = [letter]

    return set_bases
```